# Modify a list based on another list and additional criteria

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have deleted the previous question and rewritten it

I have 2 lists of size `n` (let's assume it is 5):

1. List `a` which consists of non-zero random integers
2. List `b` which consists of random non-negative integers falling under these criteria:

   - The elements of this list are in descending order. `i`th element is greater or eqaual to `i+1`th element
   - The sum of this list is equal to some `f` (let's assume 10)

Here, I want to modify the list `b` so that apart from the 2 conditions above, it also complies to this one:

- Every `i`th element of this list is smaller or equal to the `i`th element of the list `a`

If for some reason, it is not possible to meet all three criteria, the criterium about the sum being equal to `f` might be loosened and become `f-a` where `a` is also subtracted from the list `b`s right-furtherest element and `a` is minimum integer possible (see the last example)

Some examples (`r` is the modified list `b`):

```
a = [6, 7, 14, 16, 5]
b = [8, 2, 0, 0, 0]

r = [6, 4, 0, 0, 0]


a = [10, 1, 14, 16, 5]
b = [8, 2, 0, 0, 0]

r = [8, 1, 1, 0, 0]


a = [10, 5, 14, 16, 5]
b = [8, 2, 0, 0, 0] # here, b is already complying to all criteria and result should not change

r = [8, 2, 0, 0, 0]

# another example where this list is of size 14 with `f` being also 14
a = [7, 5, 14, 16, 5, 7, 203, 22, 10, 4, 5, 8, 12, 9]
b = [8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

r = [7, 5, 2,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

a = [5, 1, 1, 1, 1]
b = [8, 2, 0, 0, 0]

r = [5, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

My `numpy` approach which is valid for the case where `b` does not need any editing:

```py
a = [10, 5, 14, 16, 5]

b = [8, 2, 0, 0, 0]

def edit(a, b):
    a_ = np.array(a)
    b_ = np.array(b)
    criteria_check = (a_[:len(b_[b_>0])] >= b_[b_>0])
    if criteria_check.all():
        return b
    else:
        pass


edit(a, b)
[8, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Adding another approach which solves the last example case in numpy:

```py
a = [5, 1, 1, 1, 1]
b = [8, 2, 0, 0, 0]

a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)

def edit2(f, s):
    diff = f - s
    s[(s + diff).cumsum()<sum(s)] = (s + diff)[(s + diff).cumsum()<sum(s)]
    return s
```

Comment: And where exactly is your error?

Comment: I am asking about how to construct the `else` part of my function

Comment: this is my problem. I ask about directions :) already posted what I have come up in numpy. Yet, it is not enough, because it only covers one of the examples I have. If I knew how to construct the else part, why would I ask

Comment: Can you combine them? I mean put the edit2 into the else block.

Comment: Hi, please correct me: `right-furtherest element` = last element of b? If so, initially in your examples, the last element is 0, if you substract from 0 you get a negative int, is that allowed?

Answer (score 1):

This solution works on all of your test cases:

```py
def solve(a, b):
    f = 0
    for i in range(len(a) - 1):
        if (a[i] < b[i]):
            b[i+1] += (b[i] - a[i])
            b[i] = a[i]
            f += a[i]
        else:
            f += b[i]

    x = 0
    if sum(b) > sum(a):
        x = sum(b) - sum(a)

    b[-1] = sum(b) - f - x

    return b
```